# Can I use setattr to dynamically create a property?

Tags: python

I'm creating a class that takes a variable length set of keys and creates attributes for each of them:

```
class C:
  def __init__(self, keys_values: Dict[str, int]):
    for k, v in keys_values.item():
      setattr(self, k, v)
```

I want to take this a step further and set custom setters and getters for each of these attributes. I tried:

```
class C:
  def __init__(self, keys_values):
    for k, v in keys_values.items():
      setattr(self, f'_{k}', v)
      setattr(self, k, property(
        lambda: self._getter(k),
        lambda v: self._setter(k, v)
      ))

  def _getter(self, k):
    return getattr(self, f'_{k}')

  def _setter(self, k, v):
    # Do some custom stuff
    setattr(self, f'_{k}', v)


c = C({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
print(c._a)
print(c.a)
```

but the `c.a` prints out as a property object `<property object at 0x7fe9dc1009a0>`. Is there an extra step I need to do to have it register is a property of `c`? And overall is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: What's the point of this? It seems like you're reinventing named tuples or dictionaries.

Comment: @Barmar good question. I've stripped down my actual class implementation which has a whole lot of other machinery that named tuples and dictionaries won't be able to express.

Comment: The `@property` decorator defines the name as a class attribute. Maybe it doesn't work as an instance attribute like this.

Comment: Exactly. The `property` type implements the descriptor protocol, but that isn't triggered by instance attributes, only class attributes.

Comment: Yep. I'm about to call it a day on this harebrained scheme and try a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you probably shouldn't:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, keys_values):
        for k, v in keys_values.items():
            setattr(self, f'_{k}', v)
            prop = property(lambda self, k=k: C._getter(self, k))
            prop = prop.setter(lambda self, v, k=k: C._setter(self, k, v))
            setattr(C, k, prop)

    def _getter(self, k):
        print(f'Getter called for {k}')
        return getattr(self, f'_{k}')
    
    def _setter(self, k, v):
        print(f'Getter called for {k}')
        setattr(self, f'_{k}', v)


c = C({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
print(c._a) # 1
print(c.a) # Getter called for a; 1
c.a = 2 # Setter called for a
print(c.a) # Getter called for a; 2
```

A `property` is set on the class, not the instance.

This means you need use `setattr` on the class.

A `property` also returns a `property` object with a `getter`, `setter` and `deleter` method. Those methods are typically wrapping the classes methods.

So this creates a property object wrapping `C._getter` with it's `getter` method.

```
prop = property(lambda self, k=k: C._getter(self, k))
```

This wraps the `setter` method on that `property` with `C._setter`.

```
prop = prop.setter(lambda self, v, k=k: C._setter(self, k, v))
```

And finally using `setattr(C, k, prop)` to set a class attribute as that `property` object.

A `k=k` hack is required for the `lambda`s since they are late-binding and would otherwise all refer to the same `k`.

This falls short when you want to pass different keys for `keys_values` since you're setting the `property`s on the class, not each individual instance.

What that would mean, is all instances would have access to the same attributes, or `property`s as other instances but would sometimes raise  an `AttributeError`. (Depending on whether the setter was called first or not).

Comment: This isn't going to work if more than one instance of the class is ever created - since the properties must necessarily exist on the class, rather than the instance.

Comment: Which is why you shouldn't use it. It will work on more than one instance if said instance always passes the same keys for `kwargs`.

Comment: Thanks @Axe319 yeah I would need to instantiate with different sets of keys. Appreciate it all the same.